# Is it possible to have a selected and unselected state of a single image placed in an imagebutton?

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have an image for a button. Here it is:

[image]

My task is to create a `selected` and `unselected` state of this image. This image will be my unselected state.

Using the same image, my task is to create a selected button with darker background. Is it possible to darken the image in Java?

> NOTE:
>   I have knowledge that I can do this my using an external software and have another image for selected button. However, should my idea be real and was already implemented in Android, it would actually benefit more people. So, upon research, I have not found possible ways to do this. If this is possible, surely I have missed something great.

Comment: Think, no possibility. You have to use two images for two states.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can have a darker image and when clicked in `onClick() of onClickListener` you can set the alpha `setAlpha` of this image to 0.5 or you need to implement `selectors` with two different images/states.